# Where is SqlDataSource getting default list of connection strings?

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

Aspnet 3.5. I am using the Configure Data Source wizard to configure a SqlDataSource in a new project in a new solution and under "Which data connection should your app use to connect to the db?" I am being given a ddl of two connection strings to choose from (in addition to the ability to create a new connection.)

The question is, where is the wizard picking up those two connection strings? The names displayed are from one of my other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are connections previously used and recorded by the Server Explorer. If you want them removed, go to View and Server Explorer and delete them from the list.